# Dirichlet-to-Neumann map's estimate for mixed boundary value problems

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

The study on DtN or NtD maps for Dirichlet or Neumann boundary value problems (or PML for Helmholtz exterior problems) is pretty mature and there are tons of papers on this topic, yet I couldn't find anyone has studied anything on mixed boundary value problems.

To be specific, consider a model problem
on $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with Lipschitz boundary,
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = 0 & \text{in }\Omega,\\
u=g & \mbox{on }\Gamma_D,\\
\partial_n u=g_N & \text{on }\Gamma_N, 
\end{cases}
where $\partial\Omega = \bar\Gamma_D \cup \bar\Gamma_N$, $\Gamma_N \cap \Gamma_D =\emptyset$.

I am curious is there any literature the DtN map (existence, estimates, explicit construction like layer potentials) **ONLY** on the Dirichlet boundary: $$\mathcal{V}: H^{1/2}(\Gamma_D) \to H^{-1/2}(\Gamma_D),$$
such that
$$
\|\mathcal{V}g\|_{-1/2,\Gamma_D} ^2 \leq \langle\mathcal{V}g, g\rangle_{\Gamma_D} + (\text{terms on } \Gamma_N).
$$